# Connectivity to Azure Event Hub

Tags: spring-boot, azure

I have few spring apis in cloud (not in azure). How can I make a call to Azure event hub service from these apis for a real time data feed?

should I try out the spring dependencies which enable this connectivity

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official Microsoft documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send

And this guy's repo:

- https://github.com/esalomon/spring-event-hubs1